# How do I get base conda in VSC without launching VSC from conda navigator?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, vscode-extensions

Base conda gives an error message when I run code in VSC without first opening the anaconda navigator then launching VSC from anaconda navigator.

I get the following error message when running code directly from VSC without first opening the anaconda navigator:

"conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- conda activate base
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
  ```

I have ensured that the conda path appears when checking in View Advanced Setting> Environment Variables> Path

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that you have set the conda PATH in the environment variable, you can add the following example codes to your USER `settings.json` in VSCode:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH":"C:\\path\\to\\conda\\bin;${env:PATH}"
  },
```

Comment: Added                                                                              
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH":"C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\conda.bat;${env:PATH}"
    },                                                                               
to json settings but didn't work. Also should the paths in the json settings match those in conda prompts exactly? For example scripts path has conda.exe in conda prompt but conda-scripts.py in json.

Comment: If you change "terminal.integrated.env.windows" to `"PATH": "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Scripts;${env:PATH}"`, will it work?